# whats the error means when use TextureView with the same SurfaceTexture at switch activities?

Tags: android, canvas, surface, textureview

I want Aactivity jump to Bactivity,they are all playing video. I use lockCanvas() and unlockCanvasAndPost() for rendering bitmap.

when switch activity,I remove Aactivity's textureview and pass the saved surfacetexture to Bactivity.And Bactivity use the saved surfacetexture with a new textureview.

when I use the same SurfaceTexture when switch Activity,I have a error, the log:

```
A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x7dc35000 (code=1), thread 14119 (Thread-1108)

04-15 11:33:04.314 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-15 11:33:04.314 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ UUID: c16ebdbd-1c06-4fcc-af95-e32b9c7fc021
04-15 11:33:04.314 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'Sony/C6833/C6833:4.4.4/14.4.A.0.108/k___jQ:user/release-keys'
04-15 11:33:04.314 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '0'
04-15 11:33:04.314 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 13365, tid: 14119, name: Thread-1108 >>> com.test.myexample <<<
04-15 11:33:04.314 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 7dc35000
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 0000001b r1 7a99cb5c r2 ff21221e r3 7dc34dd0
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 7dc35000 r5 446110e0 r6 7a99cc7c r7 000000fe
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 ff21221e r9 ff21221e sl ff21221e fp 0000003f
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 02460246 sp 7a99cb20 lr 4048732d pc 4054f67e cpsr 200f0030
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d0 000165b8000165b8 d1 000165b8000165b8
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d2 4480400044e51000 d3 0000040244805000
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d4 44e4fffe3f000000 d5 4480400044e50ffe
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d6 0002cb700002cb70 d7 0002cb700002cb70
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d8 000007283f000000 d9 0000000000000000
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d16 4140000000000000 d17 000000003f800000
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d18 0000000000000000 d19 0000000000000000
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d20 76fe1d90c4226ab4 d21 dcb6834829dad06c
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d22 ff00000000000000 d23 4080000000000000
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d24 026cf54a026c9bdc d25 026da826026d4eb8
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d26 026b8f92026b3624 d27 026c426e026be900
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d28 0269026902680268 d29 026a026a026a0269
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ d30 0000000000000000 d31 0000000000000000
04-15 11:33:04.384 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ scr 28000013
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 pc 0016767e /system/lib/libskia.so (S32_opaque_D32_nofilter_DX_neon(SkBitmapProcState const&, unsigned int const*, int, unsigned int*)+101)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01 pc 0009f32b /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmapProcShader::shadeSpan(int, int, unsigned int*, int)+84)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02 pc 000a6d5f /system/lib/libskia.so (SkARGB32_Shader_Blitter::blitRect(int, int, int, int)+238)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03 pc 000d03a1 /system/lib/libskia.so
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04 pc 000d0483 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkScan::FillIRect(SkIRect const&, SkRegion const*, SkBlitter*)+222)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05 pc 000d0549 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkScan::FillRect(SkRect const&, SkRegion const*, SkBlitter*)+136)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #06 pc 000d0635 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkScan::FillRect(SkRect const&, SkRasterClip const&, SkBlitter*)+52)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #07 pc 000b10df /system/lib/libskia.so (SkDraw::drawRect(SkRect const&, SkPaint const&) const+256)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #08 pc 000b2571 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkDraw::drawBitmap(SkBitmap const&, SkMatrix const&, SkPaint const&) const+360)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #09 pc 0009dbb5 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmapDevice::drawBitmapRect(SkDraw const&, SkBitmap const&, SkRect const*, SkRect const&, SkPaint const&, SkCanvas::DrawBitmapRectFlags)+504)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #10 pc 000ab5f7 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkCanvas::internalDrawBitmapRect(SkBitmap const&, SkRect const*, SkRect const&, SkPaint const*, SkCanvas::DrawBitmapRectFlags)+182)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #11 pc 00077e27 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #12 pc 00077f8b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #13 pc 00077fbf /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #14 pc 0002034c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #15 pc 00050fcf /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #16 pc 000297e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #17 pc 00030c6c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #18 pc 0002e304 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #19 pc 00063431 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #20 pc 00063455 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #21 pc 00058133 /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #22 pc 0000d258 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #23 pc 0000d3f0 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cae0 000000f9
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cae4 000001f4
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cae8 000001f5
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99caec 000001f6
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99caf0 000001f7
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99caf4 000001f8
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99caf8 000001f9
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cafc 000001fa
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb00 000003f6
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb04 000003f7
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb08 000003f8
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb0c 000003f9
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb10 440524e5 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb14 439186bd /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb18 000007f7
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb1c 000007f8
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 7a99cb20 7dc34dd0
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb24 000000fe
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb28 00000134
04-15 11:33:04.394 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb2c 7a99d6d8 [stack:14119]
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb30 7dc34dd0
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb34 000005f4
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb38 000000fe
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb3c 40552aef /system/lib/libskia.so
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb40 4054f619 /system/lib/libskia.so (S32_opaque_D32_nofilter_DX_neon(SkBitmapProcState const&, unsigned int const*, int, unsigned int*))
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb44 4048732d /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmapProcShader::shadeSpan(int, int, unsigned int*, int)+86)
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01 7a99cb48 0000033d
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb4c 0000ff8b
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb50 0000ff8c
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb54 0000033d
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb58 00000123
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb5c 02140214
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb60 02150215
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb64 02160215
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb68 02170216
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb6c 02170217
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb70 02180218
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb74 02190218
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb78 02190219
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb7c 021a021a
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb80 021b021a
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb84 021b021b
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........ ........
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02 7a99cd80 00000728
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cd84 75d74cae /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.test.myexample-1.apk@classes.dex
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cd88 76aa6eb8
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cd8c 6d5327d0 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cd90 00000000
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cd94 00000000
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cd98 00000001
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cd9c 7a99dc40 [stack:14119]
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cda0 00000000
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cda4 4048ec71 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkARGB32_Shader_Blitter::blitRect(int, int, int, int))
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cda8 00000000
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cdac 76a8da80
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cdb0 7a99d3c0 [stack:14119]
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cdb4 7a99d338 [stack:14119]
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cdb8 7a99d934 [stack:14119]
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cdbc 7a99dad0 [stack:14119]
04-15 11:33:04.404 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........ ........
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r1:
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb3c 40552aef 4054f619 4048732d 0000033d
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb4c 0000ff8b 0000ff8c 0000033d 00000123
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb5c 02140214 02150215 02160215 02170216
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb6c 02170217 02180218 02190218 02190219
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb7c 021a021a 021b021a 021b021b 021c021c
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb8c 021d021c 021e021d 021e021e 021f021f
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb9c 0220021f 02200220 02210221 02220221
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cbac 02220222 02230223 02240223 02240224
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cbbc 02250225 02260226 02270226 02270227
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cbcc 02280228 02290228 02290229 022a022a
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cbdc 022b022a 022b022b 022c022c 022d022d
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cbec 022e022d 022e022e 022f022f 0230022f
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cbfc 02300230 02310231 02320231 02320232
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cc0c 02330233 02340234 02350234 02350235
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cc1c 02360236 02370236 02370237 02380238
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cc2c 02390238 02390239 023a023a 023b023b
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r3:
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34db0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34dc0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34dd0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34de0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34df0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34e00 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34e10 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34e20 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34e30 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34e40 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34e50 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34e60 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34e70 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34e80 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34e90 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34ea0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r4:
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34fe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc34ff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc35000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc35010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc35020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc35030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc35040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc35050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc35060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc35070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc35080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc35090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc350a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc350b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc350c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7dc350d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r5:
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 446110c0 ff272a21 ff272a21 ff272a21 ff272a21
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 446110d0 ff272a21 ff272a21 ff272a21 ff272a21
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 446110e0 ff141511 ff141511 ff141511 ff141511
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 446110f0 ff141511 ff141511 ff141511 ff141511
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 44611100 ff141511 ff141511 ff141511 ff141511
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 44611110 ff141511 ff141511 ff141511 ff141511
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 44611120 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 44611130 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 44611140 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 44611150 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 44611160 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 44611170 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 44611180 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 44611190 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414 ff141414
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 446111a0 ff131313 ff131313 ff131313 ff131313
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 446111b0 ff131313 ff131313 ff131313 ff131313
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r6:
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cc5c 02410241 02420241 02430242 02430243
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cc6c 02440244 02450244 02450245 02460246
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cc7c 02470246 02470247 02480248 02490248
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cc8c 024a0249 024a024a 024b024b 024c024b
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cc9c 024c024c 024d024d 024e024d 024e024e
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99ccac 024f024f 0250024f 02510250 02510251
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99ccbc 02520252 02530252 02530253 02540254
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cccc 02550254 02550255 02560256 02570256
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99ccdc 02570257 02580258 02590259 025a0259
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99ccec 025a025a 025b025b 025c025b 025c025c
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99ccfc 025d025d 025e025d 025e025e 025f025f
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cd0c 02600260 02610260 02610261 02620262
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cd1c 02630262 02630263 02640264 02650264
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cd2c 02650265 02660266 02670267 02680267
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cd3c 02680268 02690269 026a0269 026a026a
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cd4c 026b026b 026c026b 026c026c 00000000
04-15 11:33:04.414 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near ip:
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 02460224 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 02460234 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 02460244 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 02460254 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 02460264 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 02460274 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 02460284 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 02460294 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 024602a4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 024602b4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 024602c4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 024602d4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 024602e4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 024602f4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 02460304 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 02460314 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near sp:
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb00 000003f6 000003f7 000003f8 000003f9
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb10 440524e5 439186bd 000007f7 000007f8
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb20 7dc34dd0 000000fe 00000134 7a99d6d8
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb30 7dc34dd0 000005f4 000000fe 40552aef
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb40 4054f619 4048732d 0000033d 0000ff8b
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb50 0000ff8c 0000033d 00000123 02140214
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb60 02150215 02160215 02170216 02170217
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb70 02180218 02190218 02190219 021a021a
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb80 021b021a 021b021b 021c021c 021d021c
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cb90 021e021d 021e021e 021f021f 0220021f
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cba0 02200220 02210221 02220221 02220222
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cbb0 02230223 02240223 02240224 02250225
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cbc0 02260226 02270226 02270227 02280228
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cbd0 02290228 02290229 022a022a 022b022a
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cbe0 022b022b 022c022c 022d022d 022e022d
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7a99cbf0 022e022e 022f022f 0230022f 02300230
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around pc:
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f65c fa1f3801 f855f288 ea4f9022 f8554218
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f66c fa1fa022 f855f28c ea4f8022 f855421c
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f67c e8842022 f8c40600 60e28008 36083410
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f68c dce32800 72ebea2b 0703f007 eb012400
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f69c eb0301c2 e0061302 0014f831 2020f855
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f6ac 2024f843 42bc3401 e8bdd1f6 bf008ff8
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f6bc 0006d586 ffffeff0 4ff7e92d 6803469a
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f6cc f8b0468b 460d8068 691e4654 1053699f
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f6dc e0204699 1c08f855 39fff109 0c09b288
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f6ec fb070080 46410c01 000cf856 000ce88d
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f6fc f904f738 2c04f855 0c11b293 0c08f844
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f70c fb070098 46410201 f73858b0 f844f8f7
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f71c e89d0c04 3508000c f1b93408 dcd90f00
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f72c ea2307d1 d50c74e3 0034f85b 0c01b282
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f73c fb070093 46413701 f73859f0 f84af8df
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4054f74c e8bd0034 00008ffe 4ff0e92d 6803469a
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around lr:
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4048730c 454d9b03 462cbfb4 4630464c 4622a904
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4048731c 46439300 463047d0 4622a904 47d8463b
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4048732c d0031b2d eb0744a0 e7e90784 7d05f50d
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4048733c 8ff0e8bd 4ff0e92d 7d05f5ad 40fcf8d0
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4048734c 92034688 9d8e461f 0688f100 9500b11c
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4048735c 47a04630 f8d0e01f f44fa100 f8d07100
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4048736c 4630b108 fa38f003 9b034681 bfb4454d
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4048737c 464c462c a9044630 93004622 47d04643
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4048738c a9044630 463b4622 1b2d47d8 44a0d003
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 4048739c 0744eb07 f50de7e9 e8bd7d05 b5108ff0
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 404873ac f1004604 f0020088 4620ff7c 4010e8bd
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 404873bc b99cf7fe 4604b570 461d4616 4608b121
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 404873cc 015cf104 f902f7fd 4630b116 fd62f01b
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 404873dc f894b12d 602b30f3 00f4f894 20016068
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 404873ec b538bd70 4605460c f965f034 46206823
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 404873fc 015cf105 47906f1a f8956820 6ac310f3
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory map around fault addr 7dc35000:
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ 7d610000-7d621000 rw- /dev/kgsl-3d0
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ (no map for address)
04-15 11:33:04.424 323-323/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea72000-bea93000 rw- [stack]
```

Do anyone have any idea about this error?

Comment: It's crashing in native code, down in the Skia library. Did you remember to return `false` from `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed()`?

Comment: @fadden, it returns false.Maybe it happened in remove textureview while canvas drawBitmap().I should stop the playtread to drawBitmap(),wait some time,then remove texureview.In this way, the error gone.